# How can I map one column to other in excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I am trying to map the users with their department in two different excel sheets . How can I find the user and map him with correct department in the other excel sheet .

I am not sure what would be the correct approach to this

Comment: You could use VLOOKUP for this

Comment: or try [INDEX+MATCH](https://exceljet.net/formula/basic-index-match-exact)

Answer (score 1):

As Commented by Tim Williams and Terry W. You can follow the `V lookup()` or `Index()+Match()` Functions to get the result.

Here you can refer the example as you mentioned in your question.

Formula Used Only Vlookup In B3 and Copied For Entire Column "B"

```
=VLOOKUP($A3,Sheet2!$A:$B,2,0)
```

Formula Used Vlookup With Match In C3 and Copied For Entire Column "C"

```
 =VLOOKUP($A3,Sheet2!$A:$B,MATCH(C$2,Sheet2!A$1:B$1,0),0)
```

**Description:**

In Sheet 2, data filled as there are multiple users from different department. and This Page Sheet Applied Formula Of Vlookup() to get the department for Few of Users by Matched Criteria

[image]